# When i change the route it gives me unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
Index.js 

  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>


App.js
 <Routes> 
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/about-us" element={<Aboutus/>}/>
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contactus/>}/>
        <Route path="/career" element={<Career/>}/>
        <Route path="/work" element={<Work/>}/> 
        <Route path="/services" element={<ServicesMain/>}/>
</Routes>
```

when i change my path="/services/" it gives me error please help

I have tried reinstalling react router dom but error wont solve.

ERROR ERROR
Unexpected token '<'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1W0.png

Comment: Please add the error message and stack trace

Comment: Share the code which causes the error. Changing "/services" to "/services/" would not cause that